# How to swap pictures on radio button with CSS

Tags: css, image, hover

I'm making a form for my website with some radio buttons. I already replaced the radio buttons with images, but I would like to go further by making these pictures change when people hover them.

I tried to use the this code:

```
.class : hover {

   image-background: url('http://hover-picture.jpg'); 
}
```

but the problem with this, is that the "hover-picture" stays behind, so it doesn't cover the picture I want to replace.

Comment: Whole code ( especially the radio buttons)

Answer (score 0):

It should be background-image

```
   .class:hover {
       background-image: url('http://hover-picture.jpg');
    }
```

Comment if I am mistaken. Hope it works!